# jquery mobile issue keeping the javascript data across the project

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

using jquerymobile, is there any way to keep the same js file across the file(without rest the value)?

i am setting a value on my index page, later i am retriving the data from next page, now it's giving the value as null, i understand that my values are reset by every page load. but is there any way to avoid, and keep values across the all pages?

Before using jquerymobile, i used offline storage using html5

Any good idea, appreciated..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try saving your value in `localStorage` (HTML5) or in a `cookie` (HTML).

### localStorage:

To store your value in `localStorage`, use:

```
localStorage.setItem("my_value", my_value);
```

To retrieve it, use:

```
var my_value = localStorage.getItem("my_value");
```

---

### cookie:

To store your value in a `cookie`, you can use:

```
setCookie("my_value", my_value, 300);
```

where `setCookie` is the following function:

```
// Function for storing to cookie
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

To retrieve your value, you can use:

```
var my_value = getCookie("my_value");
```

where `getCookie` is defined as follows:

```
// Function for retrieveing value from a cookie
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```